# Organisational unit entry from windows client system

Tags: windows, active-directory, thin-client

i have added a windows system to Active Directory OU using computer name, 
but due to testing reason i will be able to login using the local administrator account available in the windows system not with joined domain user.

**Q: how can i verify from the local administrator user that OU update was successful for that computer ?**

i can see from Active directory that my windows system is added in the created test organisational unit.

Command  whoami /fqdn gives below error message mentioned below suspecting this issue due to my local account.

> Error: unable to get fully qualified distinguished name as the current
>   user logged on is not the domain user..

any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you need to know which OU the PC is in or simply that it was added to AD?

Comment: yes i need to know if that PC is added to any OU..

Comment: I do not think you can do this unless authenticated to the domain.